# How do I use a parameter from an object list based on another parameter? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm not sure if I can explain this one properly, but here it goes. Let's say I have this:

```
List = {
    0: {
        payment: 1,
        value: 10
    },
    1: {
        payment: 2,
        value: 15
    },
    2: {
        payment: 1,
        value: 12
    },
    3: {
        payment: 2,
        value: 13
    }
}
```

How do I sum up the values for the 2 payments separately? aka `sumforpayment1= 10 +12` and `sumforpayment2= 15 + 13`

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript, also you are using nested objects instead of arrays.

Comment: Is the given structure correct ?

Comment: If this has anything to do with the tag "array", the top level of brackets should be square `[` `]`. If this was a multidimensional-array, then the second level of brackets would be square as well...

Comment: key / value pairs should be separated by commas, not semicolons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to return object with sum for each payment.

```js
var data = {
  0: {
    payment: 1,
    value: 10
  },
  1: {
    payment: 2,
    value: 15
  },
  2: {
    payment: 1,
    value: 12
  },
  3: {
    payment: 2,
    value: 13
  }
}

var result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(r, e) {
  var key = 'sumforpayment' + data[e].payment;
  r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + data[e].value;
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a array of objects. An object in this case is unnecessary.

```js
List = [
{
        payment: 1,
        value: 10
},
{
        payment: 2,
        value: 15
},
{
        payment: 1,
        value: 12
},
{
        payment: 2,
        value: 13
}
];

var List2 = {};

List.map(function(o) {
 if(!List2['sumforpayment' + o.payment]) {
  List2['sumforpayment' + o.payment] = o.value;
 }
 else {
 List2['sumforpayment' + o.payment] += o.value;
 }
});

console.log(List2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

These days i like this symbol iterator thingy when it comes to the objects.

```js
var list = {
    0: {
        payment: 1,
        value: 10
    },
    1: {
        payment: 2,
        value: 15
    },
    2: {
        payment: 1,
        value: 12
    },
    3: {
        payment: 2,
        value: 13
    }
},
     res = [];
list[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){
                          var oks = Object.keys(this),
                          payment = {1:0,2:0};
                          for (var key of oks) this[key].payment === 1 ? payment["1"] += this[key].value
                                                                       : payment["2"] += this[key].value;
                          yield payment;
                        };
res = [...list];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please revise your JavaScript object as it is not formatted properly.

Properties should be separated by commas.

You could create an utility function which iterate over your object searching for a payment identification value and calculate the total amount.

How does it work:

- Iterate over your object properties using `Object.keys()`.
- If the value for property `payment` pass the "selector" (`paymentNumber`)
- Sum its values return the total ammount as result.

```js
var list = {
  0: {
    payment: 1,
    value: 10
  },
  1: {
    payment: 2,
    value: 15
  },
  2: {
    payment: 1,
    value: 12
  },
  3: {
    payment: 2,
    value: 13
  }
}

var calculatePaymentSum = function(paymentNumber, data) {
  var result = 0;
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    if (data[key].payment === paymentNumber) {
      result += data[key].value;
    }
  }, this);
  return result;
};

console.log('sum of payment 1 = ', calculatePaymentSum(1, list));
console.log('sum of payment 2 = ', calculatePaymentSum(2, list));
```